# My cat tried to eat a squash bug

Tags: cats

My cat, the other night, was following a bug in our house when he tried to eat it, he freaked out. He jumped up and took off running. I caught him in a different room, and there he was still jumpy and had saliva, that was somewhat foamy, coming from his mouth.

I found out that the bug is a squash bug. They are like stink bugs but live in your garden, often destroying it. One of them got in to the house.

I don't know if the bug is toxic or he was just reacting because of the smell and taste it gave off. I also don't know if they sting.

Should I be concerned?

Comment: I would bet the cat is fine by now. Most bugs just defend themselves by tasting bad, or by bring just toxic enough to teach  preditors not to eat them; it's unlikely any last harm was done. Think of it as the insect equivalent of a skunk -- noxious but not seriously harmful.